# Printing NULL instead of integer value using rJava

Tags: java, r

All required JAR files are loaded and working, PATHS are set correctly. In crude terms I tried basic operations using re.eval() and the output was correct.
I think I made a mistake in TestR.java file while using re.eval(). It prints NULL instead of the degree of the node which is 1001.

Here is TestR.java

```
package rwithjava;



import java.io.File;
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class TestR {

 public static void main(String args[]) {
 if (!Rengine.versionCheck()) {
 System.err.println("Java version mismatch.");
 System.exit(1);
 }
 String my[] = { "--vanilla" };
 Rengine re=new Rengine(my,false,new TextConsole());
 if (!re.waitForR()) {
 System.out.println("Cannot load R");
 System.exit(1);
 }

     re.eval(".libPaths('C:/Users/Karen/Documents/R//win-library/3.4')"); 
     re.eval("a<-matrix(1,ncol=1000,nrow=1000)");
     re.eval("library(igraph)");
     re.eval("g<-graph_from_adjacency_matrix(a, mode = c(\"undirected\")");
     REXP x=re.eval("degree(g,v=c(1)))");
     System.out.println(x);

    re.end();

    }
}
```

Here is TextConsole.java

```
package rwithjava;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.rosuda.JRI.RMainLoopCallbacks;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class TextConsole implements RMainLoopCallbacks {

 @Override
 public void rWriteConsole(Rengine re, String text, int oType) {
 System.out.print(text);
 }

 @Override
 public void rBusy(Rengine re, int which) {
 System.out.println("rBusy(" + which + ")");
 }

 @Override
 public String rReadConsole(Rengine re, String prompt, int addToHistory) {
 System.out.print(prompt);
 try {
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String s = br.readLine();
 return (s == null || s.length() == 0) ? s : s + "\n";
 } catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("jriReadConsole exception: " + e.getMessage());
 }
 return null;
 }

 @Override
 public void rShowMessage(Rengine re, String message) {
 System.out.println("rShowMessage \"" + message + "\"");
 }

 @Override
 public String rChooseFile(Rengine re, int newFile) {
 return "";
 }

 public void rFlushConsole(Rengine re) {
 }

 public void rLoadHistory(Rengine re, String filename) {
 }

 public void rSaveHistory(Rengine re, String filename) {
 }
}
```

Comment: Think about code format and style.  It matters - your code is hard to read.   A consistent style of intending and brace placement is helpful.  The function must have returned null instead of what you're expecting.  It'll be hard to figure out unless you can navigate into the R modules with a debugger.

Comment: So this is correct? C:/Users/Karen/Documents/R **/** /win-library/3.4

Comment: Yeah it's correct